# OAuth token generated by IdentityServer4 and validated using IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation

Tags: identityserver3, identityserver4

Is it possible to use IS4 to generate a token and IS3 to validate it?

I'm migrating our STS to .NET Core with IS4 but I have some Web APIs that won't be migrated right now.

When I request my API I get the error: **IDX10500: Signature validation failed. Unable to resolve SecurityKeyIdentifier: 'SecurityKeyIdentifier**

If I use IS3 to generate the token, it works fine!

Does anybody have the same problem?

Comment: I need more information (the token, the full exception etc) - please use the issue tracker

Comment: @leastprivilege I've opened the issue: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation/issues/98

Answer (score 1):

You can use Identity Server 4 with Identity Server 3 client side components (or even just .NET Framework components). They are communicating at a protocol level (e.g. OAuth or OpenID Connect), not a specific implementation.

Identity Server 4 is still in beta and .NET Core is only a few days old. You're going to have problems for a while...